# How should I deal with problems with two function "ui.resizable" and "css.rotate"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui

I want to make a "input" object rotate and resize by different buttons respectively, for instance, if I press "button1",then the object will become resizable(by query ui resizable),and if I press "button2",the object will rotate 90 deg clockwise.

But I found if I pressed button2 to rotate object,and I pressed button1 to resize the obj, the direction that obj resize will change strangely caused by the axis of obj had already changed(I guess) by "rotate" function ,for example, if I pull it zoom to left ,the obj will zoom to right...,I have no idea to deal with this problem, can anybody can give me some suggestion?I can't thank you enough.：）

I tried to google some bug caused by "rotate" and "resizable" at the same time, but it seems to me that there are no information to solve this problem.

you can try by :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<html>
<head>
<!please import query and query ui resizable>
<script src="js檔/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="js檔\jquery-ui.custom\jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js檔\jquery-ui.custom\jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/style.css">


</head>
<body >
    <div id="1" style="position:absolute;top:150px;left:150px;border:2px black solid">
        <input id="2" type="image" src="種子社群街區/房屋切片/實際大小/房屋6(96.25X297.32px).png" style="width:150px;height:100px">
    </div>
    <button id="3" type="button">rotate</button>
    <button id="4" type="button">resize</button>

</body >
<script>
function resi(){
    $("#2").resizable();
}
function rota(){
    var w = $("#1").width();
    var h = $("#1").height();
    var di=Math.abs(h-w);
    var obj=document.getElementById("1");
    obj.style.transform="rotate(270deg) translateY("+0.5*di+"px) translateX("+-0.5*di+"px)";

}

document.getElementById("3").addEventListener("click",function(){rota()});
document.getElementById("4").addEventListener("click",function(){resi()});

</script>
</html>
```

You can put any pic you want at "src" of input.
Please press "rotate" then, press "resize",and try to resize pic ,you will find something weird.

Comment: Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: ok corrected,please check.

Answer (score 0):

I would advise not mixing Native JavaScript with jQuery if possible. Here is a basic example.

```js
$(function() {
  function resi() {
    $("#el-2").resizable();
  }

  function rota() {
    var w = $("#el-1").width();
    var h = $("#el-1").height();
    var di = Math.abs(h - w);
    var obj = $("#el-1");
    obj.css("transform", "rotate(270deg) translateY(" + (0.5 * di) + "px) translateX(" + (-0.5 * di) + "px)");
  }

  $("#el-3").click(rota);
  $("#el-4").click(resi);
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div id="el-1" style="position:absolute;top:150px;left:150px;border:2px black solid">
  <input id="el-2" type="image" src="" style="width:150px;height:100px">
</div>
<button id="el-3" type="button">rotate</button>
<button id="el-4" type="button">resize</button>
```

For the math parts, it's best to wrap them within `(` and `)` to ensure that the math is completed first and then concatenated to the string.